# Как отличить сложное предложение с противительным союзом от простого предложения с однородными членами?

Tags: синтаксис

1)Шумит лес, лицу жарко, а со спины пробирается колючий холод.
2)В хорошую погоду лес клубился шапками сосновых вершин, а в непогодь, подернутый серым туманом, напоминал помрачневшую водную гладь.
В каком предложение союз, соединяющий части сложного предложения, а в каком однородные члены предложения?

Answer (score 3):

**Вид союза не имеет значения.**

Сложное предложение включает две (или несколько) предикативные основы, а однородные сказуемые  относятся к одному подлежащему.

**Таким образом, анализ предложения нужно начинать с выделения предикативных основ:** подлежащего и сказуемого в двусоставных предложениях, или сказуемого в односоставных предложениях, или подлежащего и однородного ряда сказуемых.

Что касается противительных союзов, то они могут использоваться и в сложном предложении, и в предложении с однородными членами.

Вы можете выполнить грамматический разбор сами, а ошибки будут исправлены.